# REST: Can we partially execute a POST/PUT/DELETE resource for API executing multiple request at the same time

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, api-design

We are an ecommerce company and we allow our dealers to list multiple products in one go.

Simplified version of API looks like:

```
{
 "dealerId":1,
 "stocks": {
        [] 
 }
```

}

Since we allow dealer to post multiple stocks in one go, what should we do in case there is some validation error. Should we successfully post correct stocks and send response message with ids of successful and unsuccessful stocks? If yes, what should be response code in this case, 200 or 400 or some other code?

For example lets say stockId1 has correct data but stockId2 has price less than 1 which is validation error.

Should we POST stock1 and reject stock2 OR we should reject both?

What does REST suggests for such situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Return `202 Accepted` to tell the client it was accepted but there is no guarantee all went well and as expected.
2. Return `200` and a list of the items which failed.

The important thing is to choose one, communicate this clearly on your API so clients are aware of it, and be consistent. In other words, do not use `202` for some operations and `200` for other operations.